# Trying to build a random number generator with a non-linear probability, but what would the function look like?

Tags: probability, random-functions

It's my first post, so hopefully I don't muck it up.

I am trying to build a random number generator with a **certain property** that I'm having trouble implementing, describing, and searching for.

It is easiest for me to describe what I have, and then describe why it doesn't do what I would like. What I have, I believe, looks like this:

$f(c, m, M, w)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{M-c}{M-w}, & \text{for $w \le c \le M$}\\[2ex]
\frac{c-m}{w-m}, & \text{for $m \le c \lt w$}\\ 
\end{cases}$

Where $c$ is some candidate value, $m$ and $M$ are the minimum and maximum values, $w$ is the weighted ("most likely") value, and the function returns the probability that the candidate is "accepted" as a weighted random number.

In case I totally messed up that attempt at a generic case, here's a specific case for a candidate number evaluator between 1 and 10, where 7 is the weighted value:

$f(c)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{10-c}{3}, & \text{for $7 \le c \le 10$}\\[2ex]
\frac{c-1}{6}, & \text{for $1 \le c \lt 7$}\\ 
\end{cases}$

This solution is fine for a linear drop in probability, but what I'm trying for is a more curved (geometric?) drop in probability. Instead of drawing a line from 100% probability at the weight value down to 0% probability in each direction toward the max and min, I'd like it to be a curve, where the closer to the weight value the higher the resulting probability (higher than a linear distance).

Did I explain this at all clearly? Is there a function that I could use to describe the behavior I am looking for? Maybe a piecewise quadratic or something? Would someone be willing to help me find that function?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you looking for a smooth step (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) function?

Comment: @EthanMacBrough I think maybe so! I'm going to give that a shot and see how it looks!

Comment: Smooth step has more of a rounded top than a sharp top.  Is that what you want?  More generally, why don't you hand-draw a few examples of various $(m, M, w)$ cases.  People might have more ideas after seeing your pictures.